# Building predictive model from HDFS OR HIVE as source of training set and test set in production environment

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

Can someone help me if the steps I have written below is how it is done in real world predictive modelling .

1. Source is Oracle database.
2. Using Apache Sqoop to bring the data into HDFS.(I use --query to bring the features into hdfs)
3. Here, I am confused as to process the data further in HDFS or directly bring the data into Hive.
4. Access data from Hive or Hdfs.
5. Data manipulation and pruning using R
6. Sample the data into training and test data
7. Build the model using R and save it as PMML.
8. Evaluate the model using ROC curve or AUC
9. Deploy the model.
10. Predict the value using new datasets.
    10.Visualize the new values using Tableau.

Please let me know whether it is a best practice to make Hive as the source of training data and test data or whether to directly make processing files from HDFS to build the model and store the results to Hive.

Which one adopts in real production environment.

Answer (score 0):

The steps above seem quite strange on several levels.  If you have your data in Oracle, you are likely using it or another RDBMS to do your modeling.  There is no need to lose structure going to hdfs and then regain it in hive.  There are several analytically focused columnar dbs that could do quite well.  Also the PMML step seems unnecessary.  Compliant PMML is only available for a few models and I have only seen it used in linear regressions.  If your data is big enough that it needs hive, using R is possible but may not be the best choice.  Using R with data that size (out of core) is fairly advanced R.
In short, there is likely a scenario where that set of steps is right, but it raises a lot of issues for me.  Ask a lot of questions before proceeding.